# DATE datatype of SQL Server 2008 returing time!

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, date

I have a column of datatype `DATE` in SQL Server 2008, which stores only the date in format "yyyy-MM-dd" but when I select the date from database via C# and converting into string, it shows the time part also like.

```
"2012-04-21 12:00:00"
```

what is the problem I didn't store time in database here is my query!

```
string sql = @"select card_no, amount, csc,expdate " + 
              "from user_account_card " + 
              "where user_id = '" + loginsession.Auser + "';";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataReader red = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (red.Read())
{
   loginsession.Cardno = Convert.ToString(red["card_no"]);
   loginsession.Cardamount = Convert.ToString(red["amount"]);
   loginsession.Csc=Convert.ToString(red["csc"]);
   loginsession.Expdate = Convert.ToString(red["expdate"]);//date part
   break;
}

MessageBox.Show("database value from database--" +loginsession.Expdate);
```

Please help me what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the time is showing as midnight then for all intents and purposes it is storing it without time.

SQL has a date data type that does not include time, but you need to re-design the table.  Not sure if you need/want to do that.

You could also try this:

```
((Date)red["expdate"]).ToString();
```

Since this will convert to a Date data type and not a DateTime data type you should just see the date part in the returned string.

Comment: ["for all intents and purposes"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for_all_intents_and_purposes)

Comment: @Martin - dang dude you are correcting my English?  Seems like there might be more needy targets on SO. (Thanks for the tip) :D

Comment: Should be ((DateTime)red["expdate"]).ToShortDateString();

Comment: @hogan :-Thanks for hints  this works in mine  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(red["expdate"]);
                loginsession.Expdate= dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Answer (score 2):

[Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) doesn't have a "date" overload, only ["datetime"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9e5b1z.aspx)

Comment: -Thanks for the info Now i will convert that it in some thin else

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 will store just date in a `DATE` column - you can easily verify that in SQL Server Management Studio. Also: a `DATE` column doesn't store a date in a particular string format - that's just how you see it. A date is a date is a date - it's stored as a date and doesn't have any "format" per se.

However, .NET doesn't have a "date-only" datatype, so reading a `DATE` column from SQL Server ends up in a `DateTime` variable in .NET which contains DATE and TIME.

So it's really not an issue of SQL Server here - but rather an issue in .NET